# Correct usage of Php MySQL prepare statement to prevent sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I just saw this following usage of sql prepare statement and was wondering if this would actually prevent sql injection to occur.

```
$sql= "Select * from mytable where id =" . $id;
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

By not using the parameterized variables for $id to provide the value later and avoid appending the value directly, I was wondering if this provides enough protection against sql injection?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You're not binding anything.

Comment: It depends on where `$id` comes from. *Never, ever trust user input.*

Comment: _Never trust any input._*

Comment: They're called injection bugs because variables get injected into the query without escaping. Here you're doing precisely that with `$id`. The reason placeholder values exist is to separate the query from the data associated with it, no values are ever injected ideally.